# Is Julia's Vector{Vector{T}} stored contiguously in memory?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia, jagged-arrays, ragged

To motivate my question, consider the case when dealing with [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) (for simplicity's sake) of element type `Int` in Julia. There are two ways to store them:

1. As `Vector{Vector{Int}}`
2. As `Vector{Union{Vector{Int}, Int}}` (especially, if one expects to store a sufficiently large number of 1-element vectors)

My question is which one is more efficient / faster / better?

To answer it, among the other things, I need to know how each is stored in memory. Namely:

1. I presume that variable of a type `Vector{Vector{Int}}`, would be considered homogeneous type array, and therefore I would expect it to be stored *contiguously* in memory, and as such to be more cpu-cache-friendly. Am I right? Or contiguity only applies to arrays whose elements' data type is primitive?
2. Would variable of a type `Vector{Union{Vector{Int}, Int}}` considered heterogeneous array, and as such stored **not** *contiguously* in memory?
3. How benefit of contiguous representation in memory is compared to the benefit of not having array container for 1-element arrays members, i.e. storing them as primitive data type (`Int` in this case)? Which one yields more efficiency?

Comment: The references would be stored contiguously, not all the data. I don't think the union or non-union type would make any substantial difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Julia's arrays will only store elements of type `T` unboxed if `isbits(T)` is true.  That is, the elements must be both immutable and pointer-free.  An easy way to see if the elements are being stored immediately is by allocating an uninitialized array.  Contiguous arrays of unboxed (immediate) values will have gibberish:

```
julia> Array(Int, 3)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4430901168
 4470602000
 4430901232
```

whereas arrays of non-isbits types will have `#undef` pointers:

```
julia> Array(Vector{Int}, 3)
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef
```

Imagine what would happen if the latter returned one contiguous chunk of `Int`s.  How would it know how big to make it? Or where one vector stopped and the next began? It would depend upon the sizes of the vectors, which isn't known yet.

A `Vector{Union{Vector{Int}, Int}}` will similarly store its elements as pointers; this time it's because Julia doesn't know how to interpret each element inline (should it read the memory like an integer or like an array?). It has the additional disadvantage that Julia no longer knows what type it'll return from indexing.  This is a type-instability, and will certainly be *much* worse for performance than just using one-element vectors.

It is possible to create your own ragged array type that stores its elements inline, but it's very tricky to make it work with the standard library like a normal array since it breaks a lot of assumptions about how indexing works.  You can take a look at my latest attempt: [RaggedArrays.jl](https://github.com/mbauman/RaggedArrays.jl).  You can see how I compare it to previous efforts in [Issue#2](https://github.com/mbauman/RaggedArrays.jl/issues/2).

Comment: Also look at `SparseMatrix` if it fits the application. The non-zero elements are stored continuously (columns are continuous). Thus, indexing would be fast. This would work nicely if the elements you have are all non-zero (or can be made so).

Comment: Also note that even though RaggedArray's elements are stored contiguously, it still needs to look up its indices from a secondary array (in most usages).  I've not benchmarked or optimized it thoroughly, so I wouldn't be at all surprised if there are cases where `Vector{Vector{T}}` is faster.